# VSCode : navigate to most recently added variable in watch window

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have the following [multicommand](https://github.com/ryuta46/vscode-multi-command) in my `keybindings.json/settings.json` files:

```
"command": "multiCommand.cursorwatch",
 "sequence": [
      "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
      "editor.debug.action.selectionToWatch",
      "workbench.debug.action.focusWatchView"
  ]
```

This, essentially, adds the variable under the cursor to the watch window while inside a debugging session.

While the `workbench.debug.action.focusWatchView` indeed focuses on the watch window after adding the variable under the cursor, it does NOT focus on the most recently added variable. It focuses on the watch window "in general" and one needs further keystrokes to navigate to the bottom where the most recently added variable resides.

Is there any command to directly navigate to the bottom-most variable in the watch window that can be added to the above multicommand so that the focus after the operation is on the most recently added variable?

See example below:

[image]

---

Edited to add:

Adding:

```
"list.focusLast",
"list.focusPageDown"
```

to the multicommand brings focus to the *penultimate* entry, but surprisingly, not to the *last* entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When stopped on a breakpoint, you are correct that `list.focusLast` stops at the penultimate watch entry.  I tried adding a small delay between commands and it seems to work fine - going to and selecting the last entry (you could try even smaller `intervals` to see if they work too.

```
{
  "key": "alt+i",                                // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "interval": 100,
    "sequence": [
          "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
          "editor.debug.action.selectionToWatch",
          "workbench.debug.action.focusWatchView",
          "list.focusLast",
          "list.select
      ]
    }
}
```